# How create a function that find the deepest leaf of a tree and build the pathname

Tags: python, path, tree

I have create this simple function that from a matrix that contain: dad, child, deep and built the deepest pathname.
for example:

```
matrix[n][0]=dad
matrix[n][1]=child
matrix[n][2]=deep
```

file_data.append(matrix)

Next I insert my matrix in a global variable, and with this code I build the deepest path:
(I'm not a fun of the recursion)

```
for m in file_data:
        #find the deepest leaf
        for t in m:
            list_max.append(t[2])
        deepest=max(list_max)
        #find the deepest t
        for t in m:
            if t[2]==deepest:
                p=t
        #build the path
        for t in reversed (m):
            if t[1]==p[0]:
                path+=str(t[1])+'\n'
                p[0]=t[0]
```

I think that is not the best way to create the path, but works, if someone can suggest me another way, should be cool, thank you
I should create another function that take a node, and delete all the child, in your opinion is possible without recursion?
Thank you again

Comment: By deepest do you mean the node the furthest from the root? Do roots track their depth?

Comment: yes, the furthest, and the roots don't track the depth, but in the array, each node have a field with the deep:     'matrix[n][0]=dad
matrix[n][1]=child
matrix[n][2]=deep'